# Codeigniter 2.1.3 HMVC templates from /public/themes

Tags: codeigniter, templates, view, hmvc

I'm using codeigniter 2.1.3 with wiredesignz HMVC, I was wondering how would I get templates from the public folder rather than the modules/module/views?

example structure

application/projects/projectname/ciappstructure

application/system/etc/

public/themes/themename/layout

public/themes/themename/pages

public/themes/themename/widgets

public/themes/themename/etc

I would love to use html files and have my template library sort out the tags and placement of widgets or modules, all modules and theme data being pulled from the DB

like:
$homepage = $this->load->view(FCPATH.'themes/$theme/pages/homepage.html', $data, TRUE);

Oh and another quick question, I'm new to HMVC, could I call modules::run('module/method', $params, $...); from a template library (/application/projects/project/libraries/template.php) ?

I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get anything working, any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `$this->load->view()` load  **views** with **.php** extension **not .html** files, Second, this method only load the views on **views/ folder.**

Therefore, your need config first your modules folder in `application/config.php` file. Place this on the ends of file.

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH . 'modules/' => '../modules/'
);
```

Next, create your first module with **views** as sub-folder, and create your **view file** with **.php** as extension.

```
- modules/
--- my_module/
------ views/
--------- my_view.php
```

Next, in your controller, load the view with the ubication of your module.

```
$this->load->view('my_module/my_view');
```

This must run, you can try and read more about the documentation.

Hope this help you!